# R - Twitter - json - listas

Tags: r

He realizado una extracción de Twitter de unos 3000 mensajes, incluyendo retweets, y ahora quiero analizarlos. Para ello guardé el fichero como formato UFT-8 sin BOM. La extracción original la hice de la siguiente manera:

```
library(streamR);
source('credentials.R')
filterStream("tweets.json", track = c("Obama", "Putin"), timeout = 60, oauth = cred);
```

Luego lo abro con la siguiente instrucción, llevándolo a una lista:

```
lista_mensajes_twitter <- readTweets("mensajes_twitter.json")
```

Hasta ahí todo bien. El hecho ahora es que necesitaría obtener lo siguiente, y desconozco cómo hacerlo:

1. Media de la longitud del texto de los tweets capturados.
2. Correlación entre el número de followers de cada usuario y el número
   de RTs que ha recibido dicho usuario (de los que al menos tengan 1).
3. Correlación entre el número de followers de cada usuario y el número
   de replies que ha recibido dicho usuario (al menos hayan recibido un
   reply).

Comment: Paquetes que te servirán probablemente sean stringr, tidytext, tm, purrr, dplyr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De partida, primero descargas los mensajes como `"tweets.json"` y luego los cargas como `"mensajes_twitter.json"`. Ojo como formulas la pregunta. Además, si deseas contar retweets, un minuto es un tiempo muy escaso para capturar esa información.

`R` lee el archivo `.json`como si fuese una lista. Cada lista está compuesta por una serie de casilleros en los cuales se pueden alojar valores lógicos, vectores o incluso más listas. Usa el comando `str(lista_mensajes_twitter[[1]])` y verás de que está compuesto el primer tweet de la lista.

Dicho esto, para contar la longitud del primer tweet hay que saber en qué casillero se encuentra el texto.

```
str(lista_mensajes_twitter[[1]], max.level = 1)

 List of 30
  $ created_at               : chr "Thu May 25 14:44:02 +0000 2017"
  $ id                       : num 8.68e+17
  $ id_str                   : chr "867753126899666944"
  $ text                     : chr "RT @HoopsOverHoes_: Bro in the first pic I  thought....nvm https://t.co/BVsMV3HTWQ"
  $ source                   : chr "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone</a>"
  $ truncated                : logi FALSE
  $ in_reply_to_status_id    : NULL
  $ in_reply_to_status_id_str: NULL
  $ in_reply_to_user_id      : NULL
  $ in_reply_to_user_id_str  : NULL
  $ in_reply_to_screen_name  : NULL
  $ user                     :List of 38
  $ geo                      : NULL
  $ coordinates              : NULL
  $ place                    : NULL
  $ contributors             : NULL
  $ retweeted_status         :List of 29
  $ quoted_status_id         : num 8.67e+17
  $ quoted_status_id_str     : chr "867076974337982465"
  $ quoted_status            :List of 27
  $ is_quote_status          : logi TRUE
  $ retweet_count            : num 0
  $ favorite_count           : num 0
  $ entities                 :List of 4
  $ favorited                : logi FALSE
  $ retweeted                : logi FALSE
  $ possibly_sensitive       : logi FALSE
  $ filter_level             : chr "low"
  $ lang                     : chr "en"
  $ timestamp_ms             : chr "1495723442183"
```

Sabiendo que es en el casillero `$text` o el número 3, se procede a calcular la longitud:

```
nchar(lista_mensajes_twitter[[1]][['text']])
81
```

Para aplicarlo a cada tweet se usa un bucle, un `apply` o las funciones del paquete `purrr` (muy poderosas manejando listas):

```
library(purrr)

len_tweets <- lista_mensajes_twitter %>% map("text") %>% map_int(nchar)

head(len_tweets)
[1]  81 140 140 134 140 127
```

El resultado es un vector con el número de caracteres por tweet.

Para extraer el números de seguidores y cantidad de retweets:

```
fllw <- lista_mensajes_twitter %>% map("user") %>% map("followers_count")

rt <- lista_mensajes_twitter %>% map_dbl("retweet_count")
```

La cantidad de respuestas es más difícil de determinar, ya que tienes que rastrear todos los tweets con `id` por sobre `in_reply_to_status_id` de los demás.

La correlación la haces simplemente con cor entre los vectores.